# Execute SQL script with Azure ARM template

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-rm-template

I'm deploying PostgreSQL server with a database and trying to seed this database with SQL script. I've learned that the best way to execute SQL script from ARM template is to use deployment script resource. Here is part of a template:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers/databases",
    "apiVersion": "2021-06-01",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('psqlServerName'), '/', parameters('psqlDatabaseName'))]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers', parameters('psqlServerName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "charset": "[parameters('psqlDatabaseCharset')]",
        "collation": "[parameters('psqlDatabaseCollation')]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts",
            "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
            "name": "deploySQL",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "kind": "AzureCLI",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers/databases', parameters('psqlServerName'), parameters('psqlDatabaseName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "azCliVersion": "2.34.1",
                "storageAccountSettings": {
                    "storageAccountKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value]",
                    "storageAccountName": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]"
                },
                "cleanupPreference": "Always",
                "environmentVariables": [
                    {
                      "name": "psqlFqdn",
                      "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers', parameters('psqlServerName')), '2021-06-01').fullyQualifiedDomainName]"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "psqlDatabaseName",
                      "value": "[parameters('psqlDatabaseName')]"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "psqlAdminLogin",
                      "value": "[parameters('psqlAdminLogin')]"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "psqlServerName",
                      "value": "[parameters('psqlServerName')]"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "psqlAdminPassword",
                      "secureValue": "[parameters('psqlAdminPassword')]"
                    }
                ],
                "retentionInterval": "P1D",
                "scriptContent": "az config set extension.use_dynamic_install=yes_without_prompt\r\naz postgres flexible-server execute --name $env:psqlServerName --admin-user $env:psqlAdminLogin --admin-password $env:psqlAdminPassword --database-name $env:psqlDatabaseName --file-path test.sql --debug"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Azure does not show any errors regarding the syntax and starts the deployment. However, deploySQL deployment gets stuck and then fails after 1 hour due to agent execution timeout. PostgreSQL server itself, database and firewall rule (not shown in the code above) are deployed without any issues, but SQL script is not executed. I've tried to add `--debug` option to Azure CLI commands, but got nothing new from pipeline output. I've also tried to execute these commands in Azure CLI pipeline task and they worked perfectly. What am I missing here?

Comment: I've also checked deployment and found this error: ```A service error occurred, the container group resource failed to start script execution. Correlation Id: <UUID>. Please try again later, if the issue persists contact technical support for further investigation. (Code: DeploymentScriptBootstrapScriptExecutionFailed)```
Microsoft explanation for this error code is not very helpful: ```The bootstrap script threw an error. Bootstrap script is the system script that orchestrates the deployment script execution.```

Comment: I've also tried to create a Managed Identity with Owner rights to the resource group and use it in the deployment script, but result was the same.